# How can I delete an external folder with Android?

Tags: java, android, file-manager

I have been searching for it but theres no any answer to my problem. I am programming an app and I want to delete an external folder. For example /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder, there is a lot of ways to create and read files from a internal app folder and an external app folder, but I dont know how to acces to files in "/storage/emulated/0/...".

Thanks.

Comment: Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get at the root of external storage. Make sure that you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, including the runtime permission on Android 6.0+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public static void deleteDir(Context ctx) {

        try {
            File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                                + File.separator
                                + "MyFolder");
            }
            if (myFile.exists()) {
                deleteRecursive(myFile);
            }
        }catch (Exception ignored){
            Log.e("Delete error File: %s",ignored.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void deleteRecursive(File myFile) {
        if (myFile.isDirectory())
            for (File child : myFile.listFiles())
                deleteRecursive(child);
        Log.e("MyFolder Files Deleted!!! : %s", myFile.delete());
    }
```

- Add this lines to app `manifest.xml`

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```

**Update**
- As mentioned by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)  runtime permission request needed for `Android 6+`

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
    } else {
        deleteDir(context);
    }
```

**Your Activity**

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 101:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    deleteDir(context);
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new File("/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder").delete();
```

**@** your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Update:** As mentioned by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) `hardcoded filesystem paths might be invalid for some versions of Android`.

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFolder").delete();
```

Comment: Do not hardcode filesystem paths. That path will be invalid for some versions of Android, for some devices, and for some users.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void deleteDir(Context ctx) {

        try {
            File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                                + File.separator
                                + "MyFolder");
            }
            if (myFile.exists()) {
                deleteRecursive(myFile);
            }
        }catch (Exception ignored){
            Log.e("Delete error File: %s",ignored.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void deleteRecursive(File myFile) {
        if (myFile.isDirectory())
            for (File child : myFile.listFiles())
                deleteRecursive(child);
        Log.e("MyFolder Files Deleted!!! : %s", myFile.delete());
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).